# How to use Identity in ASP .NET Core 3.1 without EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a project in ASP.NET Core 3.1 and I want to implement Identity to my application. I've found a lot of examples with EF Core, but I'm using LinqConnect (Devart) instead of EF Core and database  - SQL Server.
I'm wondering how to implement identity to my project in a simple way.

Comment: I have just gone through this. What helped me was Mark Johnson's post here: https://markjohnson.io/articles/asp-net-core-identity-without-entity-framework/

Answer (score 5):

Basically all you need to do is to create your custom user store.

```cs
public class CustomUserStore : IUserStore<IdentityUser>,
                               IUserClaimStore<IdentityUser>,
                               IUserLoginStore<IdentityUser>,
                               IUserRoleStore<IdentityUser>,
                               IUserPasswordStore<IdentityUser>,
                               IUserSecurityStampStore<IdentityUser>
{
    // interface implementations not shown
}
```

And then inject it :

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add identity types
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // Identity Services
    services.AddTransient<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, CustomUserStore>();
    string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    services.AddTransient<SqlConnection>(e => new SqlConnection(connectionString));
    services.AddTransient<DapperUsersTable>();

    // additional configuration
}
```

It is documented in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1).